# Split macro parameters at `=` for smart enum implementation

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

Is there a way to write a macro `ENUM` such that `ENUM(Animal, Dog, Cat = 5, Horse = 2)` expands to

```cpp
enum class Animal { Dog, Cat = 5, Horse = 2 }; 

template<typename EnumT> 
constexpr std::array<std::pair<std::string_view, Animal>, 3> get_enum_map() { 
    return {{ {"Dog", Animal::Dog} , {"Cat", Animal::Cat} , {"Horse", Animal::Horse} }};
}
```

Note, the difficulty is that the macro parameters `NAME = VAL` need to be split at `=` to obtain `NAME` without `VAL` so that we can define `get_enum_map()` cleanly. **Is it possible to do this?**

---

For reference, the below code implements `ENUM(Animal, Dog, Cat, Horse)` (similar to [wise_enum](https://github.com/quicknir/wise_enum)) but without the ability to specify values for the enums. I have seen examples such as `ENUM(Animal, Dog, (Cat, 5), (Horse , 2))` where individual parameters are packaged as `(NAME, VAL)`. But I am curious if there is a way to do it via `NAME = VAL`.

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <array>

#define ENUM_EXPAND(x) x
#define ENUM_COMMA() ,
#define ENUM_STR_CONCAT(a, ...) ENUM_STR_CONCAT_(a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ENUM_STR_CONCAT_(a, ...) a##__VA_ARGS__
#define ENUM_ARG_COUNT_(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, X,...) X
#define ENUM_ARG_COUNT(...) ENUM_EXPAND(ENUM_ARG_COUNT_(__VA_ARGS__, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
#define ENUM_LOOP_1(f, a, b, c)       f(a, c)
#define ENUM_LOOP_2(f, a, b, c, ...)  f(a, c) b() ENUM_EXPAND(ENUM_LOOP_1(f, a, b, __VA_ARGS__))
#define ENUM_LOOP_3(f, a, b, c, ...)  f(a, c) b() ENUM_EXPAND(ENUM_LOOP_2(f, a, b, __VA_ARGS__))
#define ENUM_LOOP_4(f, a, b, c, ...)  f(a, c) b() ENUM_EXPAND(ENUM_LOOP_3(f, a, b, __VA_ARGS__))
#define ENUM_LOOP_5(f, a, b, c, ...)  f(a, c) b() ENUM_EXPAND(ENUM_LOOP_4(f, a, b, __VA_ARGS__))
#define ENUM_PAIR(name, x) { #x, name::x}
#define ENUM_IMPL(name, loop_func_name, ...) \
    enum class name { __VA_ARGS__ }; template<typename EnumT> \
    constexpr std::array<std::pair<std::string_view, name>, ENUM_ARG_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)> get_enum_map() { \
        return {{ ENUM_EXPAND(loop_func_name(ENUM_PAIR, name, ENUM_COMMA, __VA_ARGS__)) }}; }
#define ENUM(name, ...) ENUM_IMPL(name, ENUM_STR_CONCAT(ENUM_LOOP_, ENUM_ARG_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)), __VA_ARGS__)

ENUM(Animal, Dog, Cat, Horse)

int main() {
    constexpr auto arr = get_enum_map<Animal>();

    constexpr auto el0 = std::get<0>(arr[1]);
    constexpr auto el1 = std::get<1>(arr[1]);

    static_assert(el0 == "Cat");
    static_assert(el1 == Animal::Cat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't believe this is possible. Roughly, the preprocessor only considers comma and parentheses as special, there's no way to pattern-match on anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there is no way to split macro inputs at a certain char, like `=`.

However, the [better-enums](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums) library uses a neat trick by absorbing (or "eating") assignments via an `_eat_assign` helper class. For example

```cpp
(EnumType)((better_enums::_eat_assign<EnumType>)EnumType::Name = EnumValue)
```

reduces to just `EnumType::Name`, effectively removing the assignment. See [_eat_assign definition](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums/blob/f3ff0a691721609a625d25d6bff92e526cfbd469/enum.h#L409-L424).